# google compute engine boot disk is full and ssh shell not responding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud-computing

how to attach with new disk space and extend to file system with gcloud cli. vm instance ssh not responding and i tried all other ways. i have snapshot image of instance disk. please anybody tell me how to attach disk and extend file system size. we using ubuntu 18.04 on googel compute engine.  ssh shell didn't give any response.  and serial console show this message again and again.

> Blockquote
>   Sep  7 08:51:47 aexpress google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 681, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 437, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 372, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']

Comment: Resize the booting disk drive in the Google Cloud Console and reboot the instance. This should correct the problem. For details, I wrote an article on this: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Answer (score 1):

Do you tried to follow this documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) ?
I also found this step-by-step walk-through doc [[2]](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resize-your-persist-disk-on-google-cloud-on-the-fly-b3491277b718) from a 3rd party website, that worth to give it a try.

If you already added more capacity to your disk, you can use this command line in gcloud

```
gcloud compute disks resize example-disk --size 250
```

In the other hand, If your image is recent, you should just try to reboot your VM instance. The fs are supposed to resize automatically.